# sklearn and statsmodels Poisson GLM yield different intercept & coefficient

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, statsmodels, poisson

I'm trying to reproduce the same Poisson GLM with sklearn and statsmodels. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I get different intercepts/coefficents for the two implementations with the same parameters.

I'm able to produce the same Poisson GLM (intercept & coeffcients) with the California Housing dataset and a random weight.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.linear_model import PoissonRegressor
from statsmodels.api import GLM
from statsmodels.genmod.families import Poisson
from statsmodels.api import add_constant

np.random.seed(0)

cal_housing = fetch_california_housing()
X = cal_housing.data
y = cal_housing.target
weight = 1 - np.random.rand(X.shape[0])

# sklearn
Poisson_sklearn = PoissonRegressor(alpha=0, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=10000)
Poisson_sklearn.fit(X, y, sample_weight=weight)
print("sklearn: \n", Poisson_sklearn.intercept_, Poisson_sklearn.coef_)

# statsmodels
Poisson_statsmodels = GLM(y, add_constant(X), family=Poisson(), var_weights=weight)
Poisson_statsmodels = Poisson_statsmodels.fit()
print("statsmodels: \n", Poisson_statsmodels.params)
```

This yields:

```
sklearn: 
 -26.49830486992038 [ 1.39746401e-01  3.13493414e-03 -1.20353116e-02  1.13276529e-01
  2.72467867e-06 -1.80067999e-03 -3.22110564e-01 -3.17229437e-01]
statsmodels: 
 [-2.64988921e+01  1.39744878e-01  3.13459216e-03 -1.20352957e-02
  1.13272660e-01  2.72361543e-06 -1.80051074e-03 -3.22114670e-01
 -3.17235748e-01]
```

If I do the same thing with a more complex example based on the French Motor datasets from openml, I don't get the same GLMs.

```py
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.api import GLM
from statsmodels.genmod.families import Poisson
from statsmodels.api import add_constant
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import (
    FunctionTransformer,
    KBinsDiscretizer,
    OneHotEncoder,
    StandardScaler,
)
from sklearn.linear_model import PoissonRegressor

np.random.seed(0)


# freMTPL2freq dataset from https://www.openml.org/d/41214
df_freq = fetch_openml(data_id=41214, as_frame=True, parser="pandas").data
df_freq["IDpol"] = df_freq["IDpol"].astype(int)
df_freq.set_index("IDpol", inplace=True)

# freMTPL2sev dataset from https://www.openml.org/d/41215
df_sev = fetch_openml(data_id=41215, as_frame=True, parser="pandas").data

# sum ClaimAmount over identical IDs
df_sev = df_sev.groupby("IDpol").sum()

df = df_freq.join(df_sev, how="left")
df["ClaimAmount"].fillna(0, inplace=True)

# unquote string fields
for column_name in df.columns[df.dtypes.values == object]:
    df[column_name] = df[column_name].str.strip("'")

# Correct for unreasonable observations (that might be data error)
# and a few exceptionally large claim amounts.
df["Exposure"] = df["Exposure"].clip(upper=1)
df["ClaimAmount"] = df["ClaimAmount"].clip(upper=200000)

# Insurances companies are interested in modeling the Pure Premium, that is
# the expected total claim amount per unit of exposure for each policyholder
# in their portfolio:
df["PurePremium"] = df["ClaimAmount"] / df["Exposure"]


df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df, random_state=0)


log_scale_transformer = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(func=np.log),
    StandardScaler(),
)

column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        (
            "binned_numeric",
            KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=10, subsample=int(2e5), random_state=0),
            ["VehAge", "DrivAge"],
        ),
        (
            "onehot_categorical",
            OneHotEncoder(),
            ["VehBrand", "VehPower", "VehGas", "Region", "Area"],
        ),
        ("passthrough_numeric", "passthrough", ["BonusMalus"]),
        ("log_scaled_numeric", log_scale_transformer, ["Density"]),
    ],
    remainder="drop",
)
column_trans.fit(df)

X_train_glm = column_trans.transform(df_train).toarray()
X_test_glm = column_trans.transform(df_test).toarray()

weight = df_train["Exposure"].values
y = df_train["PurePremium"].values

glm_poisson_pure = PoissonRegressor(alpha=0, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=10000)
glm_poisson_pure.fit(X_train_glm, y, sample_weight=weight)

glm_poisson_pure_sm = GLM(
    y,
    add_constant(X_train_glm),
    family=Poisson(),
    var_weights=weight,
)
glm_poisson_pure_sm = glm_poisson_pure_sm.fit()

print("sklearn: \n", glm_poisson_pure.intercept_, glm_poisson_pure.coef_)
print("statsmodels: \n", glm_poisson_pure_sm.params)
```

This yields:

```
sklearn: 
 4.124215168181537 [-0.10722228  0.05199033  0.09894542 -0.06660747 -0.05954254  0.03910661
 -0.13718411 -0.1899578  -0.12651478 -0.36151809  0.01969277 -0.42176609
 -0.25457483 -0.14134056 -0.0911722  -0.07497563  0.06981522 -0.02085429
 -0.07232053  0.12899145 -0.14515689  0.04688853  0.21486726 -0.30293469
 -0.01206228 -0.31644313 -0.01840836  0.04346044 -0.0052775  -0.07950883
 -0.28392923 -0.21100361 -0.33461642 -0.09643833 -0.10685933 -0.21473891
  0.04934427  0.1484769   0.10361206  0.13007973  0.23387192 -0.18049295
 -0.37974005 -0.35206201 -0.50644269 -0.1378486   0.80677232  0.26498365
 -0.317611   -0.02144868  0.09760054 -0.0250042  -0.18900948 -0.00980373
 -0.51097373 -0.35393341 -0.22314126  0.02889336 -0.08594025 -0.01077268
 -0.55380244  0.06053386  0.14022604 -0.57337037 -0.05818151  0.1487362
  0.66459068  0.13922086 -0.0022116  -0.10949448 -0.04629049 -0.17553259
 -0.6641964   0.02860413  0.23844038]
statsmodels: 
 [ 1.52973936  0.13159964  0.2908076   0.33776569  0.17222784  0.1792825
  0.27792558  0.10163897  0.04886779  0.11231167 -0.12268793  0.25851084
 -0.18293566 -0.01574746  0.09748518  0.14765008  0.16385084  0.30864501
  0.2179635   0.16650211  0.36781491  0.07194732  0.26399918  0.43197843
 -0.08582859  0.20505633 -0.09925452  0.19869599  0.26055076  0.21182394
  0.13759834 -0.06682782 -0.01197839 -0.13558727  0.10259367  0.09216882
 -0.01570283  0.24836888  0.34749803  0.30266742  0.32913019  0.43294312
  0.01851493 -0.18087721  0.84205762  0.68768174 -0.02931722  0.91548642
  0.37358626 -0.20913413  0.08709938  0.2061241   0.08350392 -0.08045833
  0.09874572 -0.40207298 -0.24554734 -0.11458956  0.13743563  0.02261057
  0.09778136 -0.44527943  0.16904712  0.24877812 -0.46479577  0.05037204
  0.25729282  0.77307065  0.53715087  0.39574963  0.28850613  0.35176121
  0.22255239 -0.26598088  0.02860421  0.23838086]
```

I don't understand, why I get different results in the second example. Both examples use the same parameters, just different datasets.

Comment: check the matrix rank of `add_constant(X_train_glm)`. Maybe the problem is near-singular and corner case behavior kicks in.

Comment: aside: statsmodels GLM and Count model have `exposure` argument. Even if parameter estimates are estimated the same, inference, standard errors, pvalues,..., depends on the correct interpretation of weights and exposure.

Comment: @Josef, thanks for your comments! Switching from var_weight to exposure is affecting the estimates. Now the intercept and coefficients are different in both examples. I'm confused about the matrix rank. I tried `np.linalg.matrix_rank`, but the results are confusing. I get different values, if I run the same code repeatedly. Shouldn't the rank calculation always yield the same result?
For 10 iterations:
sklearn rank:  [36, 37, 30, 36, 38, 36, 39, 40, 32, 0]
statsmodels rank:  [37, 30, 24, 27, 29, 35, 24, 26, 33, 0]

Comment: @Josef, I figured out my problem with `np.linalg.rank_matrix`. I had to add `tol=0.01` to deal with different scales of the data. Now I get consistently a rank of 76 for `add_constant(X_train_glm)`. Which is the number of columns in the data and therefore there is no rank deficiency.